# Only plain permalinks working

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I've a problem with a site (part of a multisite structure).

All of a sudden all the static pages are showing the list with the last posts, except for the homepage. The single posts are working fine.

If I change the permalinks from "post name" to "plain" everything is working fine.
here the htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]


# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

what could it be? Any hint?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

My use:

```
    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# As diretrizes (linhas) entre "BEGIN WordPress" e "END WordPress" são
# geradas dinamicamente e só devem ser modificadas através de filtros do WordPress.
# Quaisquer alterações nas diretivas entre esses marcadores serão sobrescritas.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```